# Customizing style of directories in FileSystemProvider?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Making an extension that has virtual filesystem (fake directories and files) in vscode. I've managed to make it and it is working fine, but need to customize a few things and couldn't find any documentation on it.

1) For a reason I cannot specify I need to have forward slashes in directory names ('/'), but when given such a name, vscode truncates it to only last part after last fslash. Is there any way I can make this work and display fslashes in names?

2) By looking at multiple code formatting extensions, I am assuming there is a way to add additional symbols and small text to the files and directories in FileSystemProvider. Like the tslint does for ex. when there are issues in file (filename changes color, amount of issues is displayed as additional right aligned text etc.). Is there any documentation on that? How can you do that in an extension?

3) How to add custom icon to front of directories/files?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question **nr.3 "How to add custom icon to front of directories/files"**.
It is not documented in official documentation for some reason but is in vscode patch notes. It is possible to add custom icons through iconTheme, where you can set either a png/svg image or a character from a font as an icon:

package.json

```
"contributes": {
  "iconThemes": [
    {
      "id": "customthingy",
      "label": "CustomThingy",
      "path": "./config/custom-icon-theme.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

config/custom-icon-theme.json

```
{
    "fonts": [
        {
            "id": "someId",
            "src": [
                {
                    "path": "./someFont.ttf",
                    "format": "ttf"
                }
            ],
            "weight": "normal",
            "style": "normal",
            "size": "150%"
        }
    ],
    "iconDefinitions": {
        "_file": {
            "fontCharacter": "F",
            "fontId": "someId",
            "fontColor": "#F00"
        },
        "_file_special": {
            "fontCharacter": "X",
            "fontId": "someId",
            "fontColor": "#F00"
        },
        "_folder": {
            "iconPath": "./someIcon.svg"
        },
        "_folder_expanded": {
            "iconPath": "./someOtherIcon.png"
        }
    },
    "file": "_file",
    "folder": "_folder",
    "folderExpanded": "_folder_expanded",
    "folderNames": {
        ".vscode": "_vscode_folder",
    },
    "fileExtensions": {
        ".thing": "_file_special",
    },
    "fileNames": {
        "specialFile": "_file_special"
    }
}
```

After that it was also required to select the icon theme through preferences.